# taking the anti-derivative(integration)

Tags: integration, trigonometry

https://ww3.math.msu.edu/images/webwork/132/Examples/4.7.4a-eg.pdf

I'm very confused how this integral trig formula works.

(Just using $ cos x $ in this case)

$$ \frac{1}{k}cos(kx) $$

How come if the equation is for example $ \frac{1}{2}cos(2x) $ would come be how it is? My book never uses this formula in the book. However I was given this in a PDF randomly on a problem on the online homework.

Comment: Try taking the derivative of the solution to see why.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. We want to help you, but you have to help us do that. Please ask just one question at a time. Put the actual question in the post - no images. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  Show us what you have done. or tried and where you are stuck. Hint for this question: to understand whether an antiderivative is correct, just differentiate. Remember the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus

$\frac {d}{dx} \int f(x)  dx = f(x)$

So, we can just take the derivative of $-\frac 12 \cos 2x + C$ and see what we get back.  Which is exactly what is going on the the attached document.

But that is a little bit unsatisfying.

Nonetheless, from first principles you must differentiate $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ and show that $\frac {d}{dx} \sin x = \cos x$ and $\frac {d}{dx} \cos x = -\sin x.$  Which I have to assume you have already done in class and in your book and I am not going to repeat the derivations here.

Then when confronted with: $\int \sin 2x\ dx $
You are going to need to do a substitution to make it take on the form of a function whose anti-derivative you know.

$\int \sin 2x\ dx  = \int \frac 12 \sin u \ du = -\frac 12 \int \sin u\ du = -\frac 12 \cos u = -\frac 12 \cos 2x$

Comment: I think what perplexes me the most is that my book does not go into detail about this at all. How does this relate to x^(n+1)/{n+1}

Comment: $\int x^n\ dx = \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C$ is an expression of the "power rule."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule You really should know this.

Comment: But why the k in  cos(k)x be treated as if k was a power. I thought $cos x^k $ is when a k is a power of x and $cos^k x$ was the same as $(cos x)^k $

Comment: $\cos kx, \cos^kx,$ and $\cos x^k$  should be treated as completely different objects with different rules.  $\int \cos 2x \ dx = \frac 12 \sin 2x+C, \int \cos^2 x\ dx = \frac 12 (x+\cos x\sin x) + C$ and $\int \cos x^2 \ dx$ cannot be integrated into elementary functions.  Anyway, what you want to be doing is looking for substitutions such that you can make your integrals look like simpler functions that you know how to integrate.

Comment: Actually, you could say $\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x, u = \sin x, du = \cos x \ dx \implies \int \sin 2x\ dx = \int u\ du = \frac 12 u^2 + C = \frac 12 \sin^2 x + C = - \frac 12 \cos 2x + D\\$  

And by trigonometry show that since the two answers differ only by a constant, both are acceptable answers.

Comment: That's not the FTC, it's just definition of the notation for antiderivatives. The FTC concerns $\int_a^x$.